# Reading values into 3D array in C++

Tags: c++, io

I'm new to C++, so this should be a fairly basic question.

Assume I have `bunny.voxel.ply` file. This file is written out in binary, with the first 4 bytes corresponding to the (integer) sampling resolution, `res`, and the next 4 x `res` x `res` x `res` bytes corresponding to the (single precision) floating point values.

I want to read these values into 3D array `voxel`. My current code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {
    FILE* fp = fopen( "bunny.voxel.ply" , "rb" );
    if (fp==NULL) {fputs ("File error",stderr); exit (1);}
    int res;
    fread( &res , 1 , sizeof(int) , fp );
    float *voxel = new float[res*res*res];
    fread(voxel , res * res * res , sizeof(float) , fp );
    fclose( fp );
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

seems to only read the last value.

Any suggestions on how I can modify this read all values?

Comment: I think you have your second and third arguments mixed up in `fread`?

Comment: Why are you using `FILE*` and `fopen` when you tagged this as a C++ question? Use some `std::fstream` stuff.

Comment: And, this code is rather C with std::cout and new instead of C++.

Comment: I highly recommend checking the return value of `fread`.  The `fread` function returns the number of items read.

Comment: Also, check the stream for errors.

Comment: What makes you think that only the last value is read? It is highly unlikely that this is the case.

Comment: Have you tried printing `voxel[0]`, `voxel[1]`, `voxel[2]`?

Comment: I don't understand the value of printing "Hello World". Why don't you actually print the values you're trying to read?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: actually, it is a good practice to greet the world. I don't see any problems with that.

Comment: @geza: It's entirely without purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Parameters of `fread` are

```
size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE *stream);
```

Thus you probably should exchange the order of your 2nd and 3rd parameter:

```
int count = res*res*res;
float *voxel = new float[count];
fread(voxel, sizeof(float), count, fp);
```

By accident the last value was in the correct memory position so that you could identify it.

Comment: If the read is successful, then there is no difference between `size, count` and `count, size`, so the problem definitely is not about this.

Comment: @geza: That is not so. There are potential aliasing issues when you get it wrong

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: why? If the read is successful, there will be `size*count` bytes read, no matter of the order of parameters.

Comment: @geza: But you'll be writing 1 byte of a float at a time, instead of all of it. You can't just mess around with bytes in memory willy nilly. Why do you think there are two arguments in the first place?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: maybe it has historical reasons. I'm sure it has nothing to do with aliasing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: the funny thing is that this answer is wrong, but still got accepted :)